# Polynomial approximation with multiplicative error bounds

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation-theory

Problem:
Given an monotonically increasing function $f(x):[0,a]\rightarrow \mathrm{R}^{+}$, approximate $f(x)$ with polynomial function $g_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_ix^i$ such that 
$|f(x)-g_k(x)|\leq \epsilon(k) f(x)$. Here the domain is bounded by $a$, a constant and $\epsilon(k)$ is the multiplicative error bound, as a function of $k$. Also note that $f(x)$ is positive in its domain.

Has this problem been studied. I could not find any reference which talks about multiplicative error bounds. All the references, that I found out, talks about guarantees like $|f(x)-g_k(x)|\leq \epsilon(k)$, for a $k$ order polynomial approximation.

Comment: You know that $0<f(0)\le f(x)$, so any additive error upper bound $\epsilon(k)$ translates into multiplicative $\frac {\epsilon(k)} {f(0)}f(x)$ .

Comment: Thanks. I considered that previously. But I was looking for some non trivial results which may be well adapted for this particular problem.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/a/41298

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot in the understanding.